# ejecutar funciones al pulsar enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

intento ejecutar distintas acciones al ir pulsando enter. Pero no sé como realizar ésto de forma secuencial, es decir pulso enter y se ejecuta una acción, y cuando vuelvo a pulsar se ejecute otra distinta después. Sin afectar a la anterior.
Accedo a la tecla así, pero hasta aquí he llegado.

```js
 $('body').keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13){
  //ejecuto algo

  }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crear crear un contador global y hacer un patrón factory un ejemplo seria el siguiente

```js
var cont = 0;

const Evento1 = function(){
 // ejecutas tu acción
 console.log("ejecutas tu acción 1")
}

const Evento2 = function(){
 // ejecutas tu acción
 console.log("ejecutas tu acción 2")
}

const funciones = [
  Evento1,
  Evento2
];

$('body').keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13){
  //ejecuto algo
    if(cont<funciones.length){
     funciones[cont]();
        cont++;
    }
        
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: bienvenido a la comunidad, interesante solucion, sigue asi!!!

Comment: Que interesante !!

Comment: Editaste el código, porque la primera solución me daba error. Ya comprobé ésta y funciona perfectamente, pero soy principiante y no entiendo muy bien como lo hace. Agradezco si puedes, una pequeña explicación, y muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: de nada, si tenia un fallo en funciones[cont]() le puse un string de más, básicamente lo que hace es guardar en las constantes las funciones, luego se guarda en un array esas constantes y se ejecuta escribiendo el nombre del  array[numero de la posición en la que se encuentra la funcion]() y los parentesis para ejecutar la función

Answer (score 1):

Podrías crear una variable contador que incremente su valor con cada enter y dependiendo el valor ejecute una acción:

```js
var contador = 0;

$('body').keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13){
    switch(contador){
      case 0:
        console.log('Acción 1');
      break;

      case 1:
        console.log('Acción 2');
      break;

      case 2:
        console.log('Acción 3');
      break;

      case 3:
        console.log('Acción 4');
      break;
    }

    contador++;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, por la solución y la rapidez, probé las dos, ésta para mi es más sencilla de entender, pero me quedo con la copla de la otra también.